# Getting problem in storing data in Mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a Posting system like facebook. But when I am going to store my data in MySQL database, this problem is got.
Every time I reload the page, my last post is being saved again and again automatically. Here is my code

```
<?php

    $con= mysqli_connect($host, $myuser, $mypassword, $mydb);  

   if(isset($_POST['Launch'])) {

        $title= $_POST['title'];
        $desc= $_POST['desc'];
        $date=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
        $users= $_SESSION['username'];

        $q= "INSERT INTO `leashes` (`id`, `user_name`, `title`, `description`, `date_time`)
                VALUES('','".$users."', '".$title."', '".$desc."', '".$date."')";
        $r= mysqli_query($con, $q);
        if($r){
        echo 'Done';
        }else{
        echo $q;
        }
        }

?>
```

I have a login system from where I get the user's name. Please help me to overcome this problem.

Is it happening for using the user's login data??

Comment: how is the data being submitted - a traditional form submit or ajax? Incidentally your application is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Just reload the page after  `echo 'Done'; ` using php `header()`. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: @RamRaider , you don't need to have SQL injection now, as the topicstarter seams to have posted the MySQL username and password ..  Topicstarter you should change your MySQL username and password now as it was not smart to post this on a public website. ...

Comment: haha - well spotted! I hope they are not the real details!

Comment: *"I hope they are not the real details! "* Well .. @RamRaider the domain is there plus the MySQL username and database has a domain name prefix used in it which most likely happens with DirectAdmin or a other webpanel ...  So yea i would say it is mostly to be the real thing..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ooops... You're right. I shouldn't post these mysql information. But this is a test project, hoping it will not create a problem. But thanks to mark that...

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right. These are real

Comment: @RamRaider Traditional Form submit

Comment: The usual pattern is: Post the form, process the data ( do db insert etc ) and then issue `header('location:/some/page.php')` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Just unset the `$_POST['Launch']` after inserted the data.

Change your code like below.

```
if($r){
  echo 'Done';
  unset($_POST['Launch']);
}
```